# UWP mouse_event function from User32.dll do not click

Tags: uwp, user32

I have app in WPF that works fine (its input simulator for testing) for some reasons I have to convert it to UWP ver 18362.

I found, that mouse_event from User32.dll not working. I can move mouse outside window, but I can not click anywhere. And when window is unloaded then not event movement working. Is there any capability that I am missing or what?

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
private static extern bool SetCursorPos(int x, int y);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, uint dx, uint dy, uint cButtons, UIntPtr dwExtraInfo);
private const uint MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
private const uint MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;
private const uint MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x08;
private const uint MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x10;
```

...

```
        void Click(int x, int y){
            SetCursorPos(_random.Next(x + 0, x + 100), _random.Next(y + 0, y + 100));
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP, 0, 0, 0, new UIntPtr());
        }
```

Result is, that mouse moves to desired position and not click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the expected behavior that **mouse_event** method is not working in UWP apps. Because based on [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mouse_event), we can see that mouse_event is only supported in Desktop apps, but it is not supported in UWP apps.

***>>I have app in WPF that works fine (its input simulator for testing)***

If you want to implement simulating user input in UWP, please check the following article:

Simulate user input through input injection:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/input-injection.

Comment: I accepted this solution, although it is not a 100% substitution. In case like mine, that testing app is separate from tested app and clicking in different window in different app it not working.